# fread error when running a c++ project from github

Tags: c++

I tried to run the makefile on https://github.com/nasadi/Zambezi. It shows an error like:-- "file included from src/driver/buildContiguous.c:7:0: src/shared/dictionary/Dictionary.h: In function ‘readDictionary’: src/shared/dictionary/Dictionary.h:132:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]    fread(&id, sizeof(int), 1, fp);" . Can anyone help me to run the program.Do i need to install any packages.I am new to c programming.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is not an error, it is a warning. When compiler emits a warning, it means that code is syntactically correct but *may potentially* contain logic error.
In your case compiler says that return value of the `fread` function is not examined. Such ignorance can lead to a situation, where, for e.g., end of file is encountered, but the program is unaware of it and continues execution. Therefore, variable read from file have wrong value, and wrong (invalid) values may cause program crash later on.

Summarizing, if there are no other *errors*, then your program is successfully compiled and can be run.

Comment: The program shows an error as:  /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file out/driver/buildContiguous: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Manaf Mh You should read about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work

Comment: I manually created the directories and changed the makefile with another makefile available at github as:https://gist.github.com/ludkiller/f4b86da7604497f99d40 . But it still shows error as:"make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop."